# Why do speed tests suggest I'm not specifying my asp:image dimensions on my asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, image, visual-studio

I have links like this on my homepage -- 12 in all, 1 flag for all 12 languages.  I realized just doing a height= and width= doesn't work, so I followed a SE post and made my image links like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagen.png" 
style="height:15px; width:26px;"
tooltip="View this website in English" title="View this website in English"/>

<asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagde.png" 
style="height:15px; width:26px;"
tooltip="View this website in Deutsch" title="View this website in Deutsch"/>
```

It also says I'm not specifying image dimensions for my banner:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/logoussbanner.png" 
style="height:81px; width:960px;" NavigateUrl="~/" target="_self" 
meta:resourcekey="HyperLink1Resource1"></asp:HyperLink>
```

But when I run a [GT Metrix test](http://gtmetrix.com), it still says I'm not specifying my image dimensions.  Should I change these to regular html images, or is there something I'm wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This line

`<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/logoussbanner.png" 
style="height:81px; width:960px;" NavigateUrl="~/" target="_self" 
meta:resourcekey="HyperLink1Resource1"></asp:HyperLink>`

is add the style only to the hyper link and not to the image dimensions.

In ver 4.5 you can add the [ImageHeight and ImageWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.imageheight.aspx) as parametre to give to the image dimention, but on version 4 and older you can not.

Comment: Thank you Arisos.  I'm on asp.net 4.0.  I think as far as the flags, since they're all 26 x 15, I'll just add a CssClass in the asp:image tag and put a .flags on my stylesheet, and see if that works.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question!